# Performing select operations with a cursor inside a caught exception

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to write a Stored Procedure which takes input of an ID then searches 3 different tables for that item using different criteria. One solution I have is to perform the select statement on each table one by one, and catching the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception if nothing is found via the `select`.

In pseudocode:

```
Select item from from first table
    If no data found, throw exception.
        Handle exception by selecting data from second table
            If no data found, throw another exception. 
                Handle exception by selecting data from third table (if the data is not present in any row it should return 0 rows)
```

Here's what I have:

```
OPEN REQUEST FOR 
 SELECT REQ_TYPE, REQ_TYPE_STATUS  FROM TABLEONE
  WHERE TABLEONE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
  AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A');
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            BEGIN
                  OPEN REQUEST FOR
                        SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' AS REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM TABLETWO
                        WHERE TABLETWO.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
                        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                                  begin
                                      OPEN REQUEST FOR
                                      SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' as REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM THIRDTABLE
                                      WHERE THIRDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
                                  end;
            END;
```

If an item is found in TABLEONE, it successfully returns the data for it. However, the `SELECT` operations that are performed inside the caught exceptions don't seem to run as the the stored procedure doesn't return any rows.

I have separately verified that the data I'm searching for definitely exists in TABLETWO AND/OR TABLETHREE.

The syntax is valid as it compiles, it's just that it doesn't return any rows if the item doesn't exist in TABLEONE (but exists in either TABLETWO or TABLETHREE).

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar question was here: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1674663-cursor-loop-exception-issues.html I think reading this thread will resolve your problem :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Franek for this.

The referenced [linked article](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1674663-cursor-loop-exception-issues.html) explains the following:

> Cursor FOR loop is smart. It won't raise NO-DATA-FOUND as it is; if
>   there's nothing to be fetched, it will exit the loop and terminate
>   execution successfully. Therefore, if you meant to handle it as an
>   EXCEPTION - you can not.

What I was attempting to do is apparently not possible. Therefore, I have implemented it this way instead:

**Pseudocode:**

```
Search for the item in the first table
    If item was found
        select the details of it from the first table
    If item was not found
        search for the item in the second table
            If Item was found
                Select the details of it from the second table
            If item was not found
                Select the item from the third table (returning blank if it's not found here neither)
```

**PL/SQL Implementation:**

```
-- Search for the request ID in the first table
SELECT COUNT(REQ_ID) INTO requestFound FROM FIRSTTABLE
WHERE FIRSTTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A');

IF(REQUESTFOUND > 0) THEN
        -- Select the request details
        OPEN REQUEST FOR
        SELECT REQ_ID, REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM FIRSTTABLE
        WHERE FIRSTTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID
        AND (REQ_STATUS = 'D' OR REQ_STATUS = 'A');
ELSE
        -- Search for the request from the second table
        SELECT COUNT(REQ_ID) INTO REQUESTFOUND FROM SECONDTABLE
        WHERE SECONDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;

        IF(REQUESTFOUND > 0) THEN
                  -- Select the request details from second table
                  OPEN REQUEST FOR
                  SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' AS REQ_TYPE_STATUS FROM SECONDTABLE
                  WHERE SECONDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
          ELSE
                  -- Get the request from third table (will return as blank if nothing found)
                  OPEN REQUEST FOR
                  SELECT REQ_TYPE, '-' AS REQ_TYPE_STATUS  FROM THIRDTABLE
                  WHERE THIRDTABLE.REQ_ID = REQUESTID;
          END IF;
END IF;
```